# Celery task does not timeout

Tags: python, redis, celery, django-celery

I would like to verify that setting time limits for celery tasks work.

I currently have my configuration looking like this:

```
CELERYD_TASK_SOFT_TIME_LIMIT = 30
CELERYD_TASK_TIME_LIMIT = 120

task_soft_time_limit = 29
task_time_limit = 44_LIMIT = 120
```

I am overloading the timeout parameters because it appears that there [name change coming](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html) and I just want to be sure that I hit at least one timeout.

But when I run a test in the debugger the cellery `app.conf` dictionary looks like this:

```
(Pdb) app.conf['task_time_limit'] == None
True
(Pdb) app.conf['task_soft_time_limit'] == None
True
(Pdb) app.conf['CELERYD_TASK_SOFT_TIME_LIMIT']
30
(Pdb) app.conf['CELERYD_TASK_TIME_LIMIT']
120
```

I've written a test which I believe would trigger the timeout but no error is ever raised:

```
@app.task(soft_time_limit=15)
def time_out_task():
    import time
    count = 0
    #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    while count < 1000:
        time.sleep(1)
        count += 1
        print(count)
```

My questions are as follows:

1. What are the conical settings I should set for a soft and hard time limit?
2. How could I execute a task in a test which proves to me that the time limits are in place.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by changing the way I was testing and by changing the way I was importing the Celery configuration.

Initially, I was setting the configuration by importing a Django settings object:

```
app = Celery('groot')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
```

But this was ignoring the settings with the `CELERYD_...` prefix. Thus I used the new notation and called the following method:

```
app.conf.update(
    task_soft_time_limit=30,
    task_time_limit=120,
)
```

I also changed from testing this in the Django test environment to spinning up an actual Celery worker and sending the task to the worker.
If someone would supply a solution for how to test the timeout settings in the unit test it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In django settings CELERY_TASK_TIME_LIMIT is working for me

```
CELERY_TASK_TIME_LIMIT = 60
```