# Why is my Celery configuration not taking effect?

Tags: django, redis, celery

I'm running a Django app with Celery 5.3.4. I'm using Redis as the broker.

I want to configure the `task_time_limit` and `task_time_soft_limit` options, but I can't get them to take effect when running locally. I've tried setting them very low, and running a slow task that `sleep`s for 10 seconds:

```
app.conf.task_time_limit = 5
app.conf.task_soft_time_limit = 1
```

But, when running the Celery worker locally, it completes the slow task and doesn't time out:

```
2024-03-05T15:46:04.647630Z [info     ] Task slow_task[97f51f79-ac48-4aa3-9098-a3ec5a299adc] received [celery.worker.strategy]
2024-03-05T15:46:14.741217Z [info     ] Task slow_task[97f51f79-ac48-4aa3-9098-a3ec5a299adc] succeeded in 10.093100208323449s: None [celery.app.trace]
```

I've tried configuring Celery in many different ways. Here's my current config, spread out over 2 files:

`celery.py`:

```
import os

from celery import Celery
from celery.signals import worker_init
from django.conf import settings

# Set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "kosa_api.settings")

app = Celery("kosa_api")

# Using a string here means the worker doesn't have to serialize
# the configuration object to child processes.
# - namespace='CELERY' means all celery-related configuration keys
#   should have a `CELERY_` prefix.
app.config_from_object("django.conf:settings", namespace="CELERY")

# Load task modules from all registered Django apps.
app.autodiscover_tasks()

app.conf.task_time_limit = 5
app.conf.task_soft_time_limit = 1
```

`settings/celery.py` (this is imported in my app's settings):

```
from kosa_api.settings.utils import get_safe_redis_url

CELERY_WORKER_HIJACK_ROOT_LOGGER = False

REDIS_URL = get_safe_redis_url()
CELERY_BROKER_URL = f"{REDIS_URL}/0"
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = f"{REDIS_URL}/2"

# only store results for a while to prevent redis from filling up
CELERY_RESULT_EXPIRES = timedelta(minutes=30)

# in tests, run celery tasks as regular functions
CELERY_TASK_ALWAYS_EAGER = TEST
CELERY_TASK_ACKS_LATE = True

# i tried all of the following, but none took effect:
# CELERY_CELERYD_SOFT_TIME_LIMIT = 1
# CELERY_CELERYD_TIME_LIMIT = 5
# CELERY_TASK_SOFT_TIME_LIMIT = 1
# CELERY_TASK_TIME_LIMIT = 5
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you try using the time_limit option on the task decorator.

Comment: What is the os?

Answer (score -1):

**why it's not taking effect!**

It could be,

1. Config is wrong
2. Where it is placed is wrong (the file)
3. Could be some other problem

**My suggestion,
Use as below.**

1. Inside celery.py file

```py
app.conf.update(
    task_soft_time_limit=1,
    task_time_limit=5,
)
```

Or

2. Inside django settings.py file

```py
CELERY_TASK_TIME_LIMIT = 5
CELERY_TASK_SOFT_TIME_LIMIT = 1
```

[More info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47521166/13861187)

Comment: yes, this is pretty much what i tried -- my question is around why it's not taking effect!

Comment: I can't see where you tried 1st method in your provided code.

Comment: And you say you tried 2nd method. But you put 2nd method in `settings/celery.py` file. Which is not correct. As my answer says, you should put that in project settings.py file. Even the 1st method doesn't use update function in your code. You should use exactly as in answer.

Comment: Did you try above suggestions?